# how do i Get Column value from while loop

Tags: sql, while-loop

How do i get Columns value (TGLEFF) 
from select statement in while loop condition ?

```
SELECT
@id=row_number() over (order by JNANGS,TGLEFF asc ),
@JUMTRA=JUMTRA,
@TGLEFF=TGLEFF
from dt_kp_tran where NOMREK='0114800000005' AND JNANGS=2 

set @i=1;

while @i <=48
begin
    PRINT @TGLEFF;
set @i = @i + 1
end

-- PRINT @TGLEFF doesn't give me result
```

Comment: I doubt this whole script makes sense... But anyway, what does `PRINT @TGLEFF`give you and what is the result you're expecting?

Comment: i wanna use @TGLEFF in some later processing. Sorry The result is only show data from last record ( record no 48)

Comment: You set the variable and then you print it 48 times. Makes no sense to me. Show what you get and what you expect to get.

Comment: I didn't thin you could set variables like this while in a select.  Perhaps using select into but not assignemnts directly in the select.  Perhaps you need a cursor or... shrug...

Comment: The result show it prints 48 times but only data from the last record ( etc. record no 48)

Comment: variables only have a single value - you are expecting it to loop over the results of the `select` which is not the case.  perhaps you want a `cursor` instead.

Comment: @xQbert i can get the value. but it only show value from rows no 48 which is print for 48 times.

Comment: @D Stanley : is there any chance i get the value from each record with this method? i prefer cursors for last alternativ.

Comment: You can use coalecase to collect all the results. Some thing like this  @JUMTRA = COALESCE(@JUMTRA + ', ' + RTRIM(JUMTRA ), '')

Comment: Depending if you need each item in the set or process the set as a whole, you could insert into a #temp table and then reference the temp table from the next step (assuming in same procedure) if not same then you'd have to use a table that has a longer scope, and then you have to worry about muti user or multiple instnaces... IMO not enough info here to provide a valid response other than curosr.

Comment: thanks everyone. xQbert ill try those then. COALESCE new method to hear gotta check those too.